# Scaling points and choosing colors with plot_ly R package

Tags: r, plotly

I have just started using plotly in R and it is working great but I cannot figure out how to do two things.

1) I need to pick the colors of my split. Currently, I am splitting by Territory and plotly doesn't allow me to code what colors I want each territory to be. 
2) I also need to scale the points so that some markers are very large. I tried creating a size for each row and setting size = ~size and sizes = c(2, 100) but this did not work.

Any advice on how to do this? I've tried reading the plotly R reference guide but cannot figure out how to do this with plotly_mapbox. I've pasted my code without the size or color attempt because I could never get it to work.

```
p <- df %>%
  plot_mapbox(lat = ~lat, lon = ~lon,
              split = ~Territory, 
              mode = 'scattermapbox',
              text = df$text,
              hoverinfo = "text"
              ) %>%
  layout(title = 'Ship to Zip Codes',
         font = list(color='white'),
         plot_bgcolor = '#191A1A', 
         paper_bgcolor = '#191A1A',
         mapbox = list(style = 'dark'),
         legend = list(orientation = 'h',
                  font = list(size = 8)),
         margin = list(l = 25, r = 25,
                       b = 25, t = 25,
                       pad = 2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the marker size via `marker = list(size = 2)`.

Setting the colors is more tricky and cannot be done directly with `plot_mapbox` as far as I know.

---

But we can assign a new column to our data frame

```
df$colors <- factor(df$class, levels = unique(df$class))
```

then define our own color list

```
cols <- c("red", "blue", "black", "green", "orange", "cyan", "gray50")
```

and finally plot everything via `plot_geo`

```
plot_geo(df) %>%
  add_markers(
    x = ~reclong, y = ~reclat, color = ~colors, colors = cols, marker = list(size = 2))
```

---

The whole code to get the custom colors in a scatter map in Plotly.

```
library(plotly)

df = read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bcdunbar/datasets/master/meteorites_subset.csv')

df$colors <- factor(df$class, levels = unique(df$class))
cols <- c("red", "blue", "black", "green", "orange", "cyan", "gray50")

plot_geo(df) %>%
add_markers(x = ~reclong, 
            y = ~reclat, 
            color = ~df$colors, 
            colors = cols, 
            marker = list(size = 2))
```

[image]