# problems with plotly and plot_mapbox

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to make a plotly plot that should be rather straightforward, but am having some difficulty.

What I'd like to do is plot each of the lat and longs and color them based on the count column. If I hover over a location, I should see the name in the name field.

I feel as though the code below is close, but as you'll note, I do not have any of the hover functionality.

```
library(plotly)

#note you might need a token from here: https://www.mapbox.com/help/how-access-tokens-work/
Sys.setenv("MAPBOX_TOKEN" = "my_token")

data <- structure(list(lat = c(32.6310392784338, 32.1837229125793, 31.7739571914213, 
32.4667576871354, 31.549376888011, 32.7433574730586), lon = c(-97.1339747215662, 
-97.5812910874207, -97.9910568085787, -97.2982563128646, -98.215637111989, 
-97.0216565269414), count = c(1, 2, 5, 15, 20, 35), name = c("text_to_display1", 
"text_to_display2", "text_to_display3", "text_to_display4", "text_to_display5", 
"text_to_display6")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), .Names = c("lat", "lon", "count", "name"))

plot_ly <- data %>% 
  plot_mapbox(lat = ~lat, 
              lon = ~lon, 
              #split = ~count, 
              color = ~count, 
              colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 9, name = "Blues"), 
              mode = 'markers') %>% 
  layout(title = 'A Title',
         font = list(color='white'),
         plot_bgcolor = '#191A1A', paper_bgcolor = '#191A1A',
         mapbox = list(style = 'dark'),
         legend = list(orientation = 'h',
                       font = list(size = 8)),
         margin = list(l = 25, r = 25,
                       b = 25, t = 25,
                       pad = 2),
         showlegend = FALSE)

plot_ly


R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bindrcpp_0.2       RColorBrewer_1.1-2 readr_1.1.1        plotly_4.7.1      
[5] ggplot2_2.2.1      devtools_1.13.1   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.14      git2r_0.19.0      plyr_1.8.4        bindr_0.1        
 [5] tools_3.3.3       digest_0.6.12     viridisLite_0.2.0 jsonlite_1.5     
 [9] evaluate_0.10     memoise_1.0.0     tibble_1.3.3      gtable_0.2.0     
[13] pkgconfig_2.0.1   rlang_0.1.1       rstudioapi_0.7    shiny_1.0.3      
[17] crosstalk_1.0.0   curl_2.4          yaml_2.1.14       withr_2.1.0      
[21] httr_1.2.1        stringr_1.2.0     dplyr_0.7.2       knitr_1.18       
[25] hms_0.3           htmlwidgets_0.9   rprojroot_1.2     grid_3.3.3       
[29] glue_1.1.1        data.table_1.10.4 R6_2.2.1          rmarkdown_1.8    
[33] tidyr_0.6.3.9000  purrr_0.2.2.2     magrittr_1.5      backports_1.0.5  
[37] scales_0.4.1      htmltools_0.3.6   rsconnect_0.7     assertthat_0.2.0 
[41] xtable_1.8-2      mime_0.5          colorspace_1.3-2  httpuv_1.3.5     
[45] stringi_1.1.5     lazyeval_0.2.0    munsell_0.4.3
```

Comment: without a MAPBOX_TOKEN it does not work for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you need a unique token for this: https://www.mapbox.com/help/how-access-tokens-work/. That said, if there are ways in which I can solve the same problem, I’d be open to them.

Comment: It works when using split. But have you seen this: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42661873/scaling-points-and-choosing-colors-with-plot-ly-r-package?rq=1). May not possible. You might have to rely on plot_geo

Comment: This is helpful but removes both the continuous gradient for coloring and the pretty dark background. Any ideas on how I can keep the continuous color scale and background? The layout function is not applied to the background in plot_geo() as it is in plot_mapbox().

Comment: it does not look possible. Someone else might know how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help. I appreciate it.